# Compare and paint characters of a string?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying paint characters of a string. I do a compare characters and when compare return true I want to paint character in their index.

Example: I have a string `string obj = "COFFEE"`, compare.equals(C) paint C red, if compare.equals(E) paint E red.

I'm trying this.

```
public void paintCharacter(string p){
            GUIText wordText = new GUIText();
            wordText.richText = true;

            string obj = "COFFEE";        
            char[] w = obj.ToCharArray();
            char c = p[0]; //convert string to char          
            for(int x = 0; x < w.Length; x++){
                if(w[x].Equals(c)){                    
                   obj = string.Format("<color=red>{0}</color>", obj.IndexOf(w[x]));
                }                             
            }

            wordText.text = obj; 

        } 

    }
```

There's any way to do this ?

Comment: "Paint" is too wide term. Paint where?

Comment: paint characters of string

Comment: a character string doesn't have a colour. What are you using to render the colour? What is wordText?

Comment: wordText is a component of Unity3D that receive HTML

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem is just that you are comparing strings and characters:

Instead of:

```
 if(w[x].Equals("C")) { ... }
```

Try:

```
 if(w[x] == 'C')) { ... }
```

Comment: I edited the post. Do you know how can I do paint characters of string ? thanks again